# Import C# Assembly to Delphi function limit

Tags: c#, delphi, com

I have been trying to use a C# dll with Delphi 10.3 using COM Interface and have encountered a very strange behaivour.

Here is my minimal sample of c#

```
namespace comtest
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("0F6BF46C-8B5F-4CCD-8E0D-71C175AD8234")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
    public interface IComInterface
    {
        public int func1(); 
        public int func2(); 
        public int func3(); 
        public int func4(); 
        public int func5(); 
        public int func6(); 
        public int func7(); 
        //public int func8(); 
        //public int func9(); 
        //public int func10();

    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("9F39DD6D-053B-4DD6-850A-DC7D370E0506")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class ComClass : IComInterface
    {
        public int func1() => 1;
       
        public int func2() => 1;
        public int func3() => 1;
        public int func4() => 1;
        public int func5() => 1;
        public int func6() => 1;
        public int func7() => 1;
        //public int func8() => 1;
        //public int func9() => 1; 
        //public int func10()=> 1;
    }
}
```

and csproj:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <EnableComHosting>true</EnableComHosting>
    <EnableRegFreeCom>true</EnableRegFreeCom>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

so if I use this assembly and go to Rad studio "Components-> Import Component -> .Net Assembly -> add " I can import this and get a nice *_TLB.pas file.

If I remove the comments of function func8 and do the same, i get "OLE Error 80131124"

So basically everything is fine up to 7 functions. If there are more than 7 functions I cant import the Assembly. Why isnt it possible to use more than 7 functions? Am i Missing something?

How can i use an Assembly with more than 7 functions. Is it possible to just extend the *_TLB.pas with additional functions?

**EDIT Workaround**

I just tried a "brute force" attempt by adding func8 to the *_tlb.pas after creating it with 7 functions:

```
 IComInterface = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{0F6BF46C-8B5F-4CCD-8E0D-71C175AD8234}']
    function func1: Integer; safecall;
    function func2: Integer; safecall;
    function func3: Integer; safecall;
    function func4: Integer; safecall;
    function func5: Integer; safecall;
    function func6: Integer; safecall;
    function func7: Integer; safecall;
    function func8: Integer; safecall;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  IComInterfaceDisp
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {0F6BF46C-8B5F-4CCD-8E0D-71C175AD8234}
// *********************************************************************//
  IComInterfaceDisp = dispinterface
    ['{0F6BF46C-8B5F-4CCD-8E0D-71C175AD8234}']
    function func1: Integer; dispid 1610743808;
    function func2: Integer; dispid 1610743809;
    function func3: Integer; dispid 1610743810;
    function func4: Integer; dispid 1610743811;
    function func5: Integer; dispid 1610743812;
    function func6: Integer; dispid 1610743813;
    function func7: Integer; dispid 1610743814;
     function func8: Integer; dispid 1610743815;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// Die Klasse CoComClass stellt die Methoden Create und CreateRemote zur
// Verfügung, um Instanzen des Standard-Interface IComInterface, dargestellt
// von CoClass ComClass, zu erzeugen. Diese Funktionen können
// von einem Client verwendet werden, der die CoClasses automatisieren
// will, die von dieser Typbibliothek dargestellt werden.                                           
// *********************************************************************//
  CoComClass = class
    class function Create: IComInterface;
    class function CreateRemote(const MachineName: string): IComInterface;
  end;


// *********************************************************************//
// OLE-Server-Proxy-Klassendeklaration
// Server-Objekt     : TComClass
// Hilfe-String      : 
// Standard-Interface: IComInterface
// Def. Intf. DISP?  : No
// Ereignis-Interface: 
// TypeFlags         : (2) CanCreate
// *********************************************************************//
  TComClass = class(TOleServer)
  private
    FIntf: IComInterface;
    function GetDefaultInterface: IComInterface;
  protected
    procedure InitServerData; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure Connect; override;
    procedure ConnectTo(svrIntf: IComInterface);
    procedure Disconnect; override;
    function func1: Integer;
    function func2: Integer;
    function func3: Integer;
    function func4: Integer;
    function func5: Integer;
    function func6: Integer;
    function func7: Integer;
    function func8 : integer;
    property DefaultInterface: IComInterface read GetDefaultInterface;
  published
  end;
```

plus matching implementation further down, worked like a charm, although i dont like to do this on my own tbh

Comment: seems like a bug to me https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/2055-import-net-assembly-list-is-empty/

Comment: actually thats the site i got the idea for the test. was wondering if anybody found a solution to this issue

Comment: @Abudinka Next time please also link your sources instead of confirming them in comments. If links exist in the question everybody would where you got it from and what you attempted already.

Comment: Have to say this is a superbly asked question. Such a refreshing change! But it does seem like a defect and you should look for a report in the Delphi Quality Portal.  If there isn't one, create one.

Comment: thanks @DavidHeffernan 
meanwhile I have been fooling around, although I have no idea of the underlying mechanis, I just manually added func8 to the tlb.pas after creating it with 7 functions and this seems to work, i will edit the question as a "workaround" solution

Comment: You might find that the TLB importer from older versions of Delphi are better at this.

Comment: interesting idea, but a quick test using xe5 didnt do anything upon adding the dll